# block quote ignore empty lines and keep opening new quotes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, blockquote

the following photo for a code that has an empty line every few lines, 
the block quote ignore empty lines and consider that as the quote end and keep opening new quotes.

that's strange since i made a blockquote once for the whole code .

[image]

> the manual solve for the issue is adding >br>" on the empty line but
>   that take a lot of time,, so the fix must be added on the blockquote
>   function it self

here is an example on this website using the same code

```
   R3#show ip ospf database
    OSPF Router with ID (3.3.3.3) (Process ID 1)

    Router Link States (Area 1)                                   (This is type 1 )
    Link ID            ADV Router            Age          Seq#                  Checksum            Link count
    1.1.1.1               1.1.1.1                        1639        0x80000005      0x0011F5                     1
    2.2.2.2             2.2.2.2                      1645        0x80000005      0x00D22B                   1
    3.3.3.3             3.3.3.3                      1647        0x80000006      0x00FCAE                  2
    4.4.4.4            4.4.4.4                      1651         0x80000006     0x00D50C                   3
    5.5.5.5             5.5.5.5                       1646        0x80000004     0x001C0B                    2

    Net Link States (Area 1)                                        (This is type 2 )
    Link ID            ADV Router            Age           Seq#                   Checksum
    10.0.0.2            2.2.2.2                    1794          0x80000004     0x000CFA
    20.0.0.4           4.4.4.4                    1801           0x80000003     0x0015DE

    Summary Net Link States (Area 1)                    (This is type 3 )
    Link ID            ADV Router           Age        Seq#                    Checksum
    40.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1796       0x80000004        0x0047AC
    50.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1796       0x80000003        0x002BB5
    60.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1796       0x80000004        0x00B024
    70.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1798       0x80000003        0x004452
    80.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1799       0x80000004        0x0010A6
    90.0.0.0           5.5.5.5                   1799       0x80000003        0x00C6FA
    100.0.0.0         5.5.5.5                   1799       0x80000004        0x00A606
    110.0.0.0          5.5.5.5                   1799       0x80000003        0x009404

    Summary ASB Link States (Area 1)                   (This is type 4 )
    Link ID         ADV Router             Age         Seq#                    Checksum
    7.7.7.7             5.5.5.5                   1799        0x80000004      0x006490
    10.10.10.10     5.5.5.5                   1802        0x80000003      0x004A94

    Type-5 AS External Link States                         (This is type 5 )
    Link ID         ADV Router             Age         Seq#                      Checksum    Tag
    199.0.0.0      7.7.7.7                      363         0x80000004        0x0072FF     199
    200.0.0.0     10.10.10.10              172         0x80000001         0x00FF6D   200
```

here is my blockquote rule

```
blockquote p {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    color:#000000;
    margin-right:250px;
    margin-left:150px;
    padding:25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3421052631;
    margin-bottom: 51px;
    background:#e9eff3;
    border-color:#87a6bc;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    }
```

if you trying to get more information just tell me to add it .

Comment: SO you would like someone to amend the behaviour of `<blockquote>` for you in every browser in the world, right? Good luck with that!

Comment: no, block quote don't work like that in all the world

Comment: i will use block quote here so you can see

Comment: edited the question, so you were saying ?

Comment: I dont see a `<blockquote>` anywhere

Comment: without knowing more I can not help. Where does this data come from?
Couldn't you wrap it all in a pre tag?.Why must it be in blockquote? Where is the blockquote tag added? How is it added? Is there a CSS rule that affects blockquotes?

Comment: `<blockquote>` doesn't mean that no formatting is done. Use `<pre>` to keep the original formatting, including blank lines.

Comment: enhanced my question

Comment: Duane this data is an output from a router CLI, and i copy/paste it. 
i have added my blockquote rule on the main question

Comment: Bramar and Duane you are talking about <pre> 
how to use it ?

Comment: <pre> does work to include empty lines on the blockquote... but it omit all my block quote setting: like border,the block quote size and padding... its like a new blockquote

Comment: how to edit them again ?

Comment: hello... any idea ?

Comment: @Barmar your fix it corrent, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<pre>` in addition to `<blockquote>` to keep the original formatting.

Or add `white-space: pre;` to your style for `blockquote p`.